# Why have I failed this review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, first-post-review

I reviewed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24118460) as `no action needed` which was an audit and I failed. I know it should not be flagged as `not an answer` (as the second comment states), because in [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) it is stated that :

> Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still
>   an answer!

So what was the correct thing to do (other than downvote) in that review audit?

Comment: A comment (any comment) would pass the review. The idea is that you'd be writing a comment like "this is not an answer".